# Using service in application

Tags: android, csv, service

I would like to do the app that checks if there are new SMS's in the inbox one time per day. If they are, app will download necessary .csv file from ftp server, write this new messages to .csv file and then upload updated file. My app should work without any interaction.

I wonder what solution will be the best for my app. I thought about service.
In service my app will check if there are any new messages till last upload, also in this service I would like to download .csv file and do write operations and upload a file. Is it good solution ? What other mechanism sholud I use ? If someone has better idea, please tell me :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can have a separate service for this functionality and can define an `aidl` file with various api to read the and write and this aidl you can put in your app.. 
You can have an interface file along with the jar file which can have a method(which can work as call back)